# Docker bash: fork: Cannot allocate memory

Tags: rhel, docker

I am trying to create 4000+ docker containers via separate demons (To avoid the barrier of 1023 veth’s per bridge). But I am getting

> bash: fork: Cannot allocate memory

error around 1800.I have increased system-wide resources (`ulimit`) and there are plenty of inodes and memory left.
Docker version 1.8
RedHat version 7

Comment: what does free report ?

Comment: Mem: 257742/19147   
swap: 16383/0

Answer (score 0):

Bash does not use `vfork` and bash is huge.

This causes many forks to comsume a lot of virtual memory.

This is most likely a problem that is caused by the real memory resources on the system than by something you can control via `ulimit`.

Did you try to use the Bourne Shell or ksh93? Both use `vfork()` to optimize the performance.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with the docker zombie process which was eating up the kernel process capacity have been able to solve the problem by increasing kernel.pid_max